Homomorphic Subtraction and Sign Evaluation
Are there any homomorphic encryption methods that allow both homomorphic subtraction and sign evaluation? Given two integers $A$ and $B$, I would like to know, homomorphically, whether $E(A)-E(B)$ is positive or negative.

Are E(A) and E(B) available? If so, wouldn't anyone be able to compute E(A)-E(B) and tell if it's positive or negative? If not, how could that be possible? Or are you asking for the sign of E(A-B) but then how would that be uniquely defined? Or are you asking if it would be possible to determine if A-B is positive or negative from E(A) and E(B)? If so, hint: if that was possible and the key allowing encryption was public, prove that decryption would be possible. Thus rule out public-key homomorphic encryption for the task.

Or, is the problem "given $E(A)$ and $E(B)$, return $E(1)$ if $A > B$ and $E(0)$ if $A \le B$".  That would not violate security.  On the other hand, that operation would imply that the system is FHE, even if that were the only homomorphic operation supported (!), and so you would likely be best served by looking into existing known FHE schemes (all of which can perform this operation).

In the binary case, use 2's complement and $-B$ and check MSB, see the articles that uses this.
